# Programmatically open product listing with filters enabled

Tags: magento2, development

Is it possible to open the product listing page in backend enabling some filter?

In particular, I have a custom module with an observer linked to a `controller_action_predispatch` event. In the observer I need to evaluate a product and, if some conditions are met, I need to redirect to the product listing page showing just that product, like in this picture

[image]

This is (partial) code from my observer

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    $product = // ...retrieve product

    if ($this->conditionsAreMet($product)) { // check my conditions

        $url = $this->backendUrl->getUrl(
            'catalog/product/index',
            [
                'filters' => [
                    'entity_id' => [
                        'from' => $product->getId(),
                        'to' => $product->getId()
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        );

        $action = $observer->getControllerAction();
        $action->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);
    }

    // ...
}
```

It doesn't work, it just redirect to the product listing, without applying any filter. If I want to open the product edit page, I can call `getUrl()` with

```
$url = $this->backendUrl->getUrl(
    'catalog/product/edit',
    [
        'id' => $product->getId()
    ]
);
```

and this works. However I'm not able to set the filters before redirecting